# Литература по PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день.
На первый взгляд банальный вопрос, но ищется литература по **PHP >= 5.3**. Интересуют издания не для новичков, а именно темы: подробное описание SPL с примерами, trait, closures и т.д.
Спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net

Answer (score 2):

"[**PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785845919229&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)", Мэтт Зандстра.